# Positive part of trace of a Sobolev function

Tags: sobolev-spaces, trace-map

Suppose that $\Omega$ has a smooth boundary, $u\in H^1(\Omega)$. I want to know whether the following holds:
$$ tr(u^+)=tr(u)^+ $$
where $tr$ denotes the trace of a Soboelv function. In other words, can we prove that
$$tr(u)\geq 0\Rightarrow tr(u^+)=tr(u)$$
I do hope it holds, but I don’t know how to prove it. Or any reference is welcoming. Thanks!

Comment: I believe the answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429242/sobolev-space-and-weak-maximum-principle) sketches how a proof of your first display goes.

Answer (score 0):

If $tr(u)\geq 0$, it follows $tr(u)^-=0$, so by linearity of the trace operator
$$tr(u^+)=tr(u+u^-)=tr(u)+tr(u)^-=tr(u).$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I wonder that why $tr(u^-)=tr(u)^-$. And the definition of your $u^-$ means $u^-=-min(u,0)$ right?